# WPF DataGrid, ObservableCollection Updates, and Redrawing

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I will try to keep this as brief as possible, but there is a fair amount of nuance to this question.

**The Workflow**

I am working in C# and am using WPF and MVVM for the UI for an addin for Revit (a 3D modeling software from Autodesk).

The overarching goal is to create a window that shows the parameters of a 3D element after it is selected. This is a filtered list that are specific to my organization and our users needs, and allow the user to edit them in order to streamline their workflow. The complication is that because I am working with an API I can only use what tools I am given when interacting with the model.

The issue I am running into lies in the workflow. I have detailed the workflow below.

- User Selects a 3D Element
- The addin uses the API to pull the parameters and wraps them in a wrapper class and adds them into a custom `ObservableCollection` to display them in the `DataGrid`
- The user then changes a value in the `DataGrid`. When the cell loses focus it fires off a command  that hooks the API and updates the parameter's value.
- The change is made and the internal logic of the element calculates it's values based on the changed parameter
- The calculated parameter values are changed in the model
- The ViewModel checks each parameter to see if its value has changed, and updates any of the wrapped parameters in the `ObservableCollection` to reflect the changes.
- The `ObservableCollection` fires off it's collection changed event to notify the `DataGrid` that values have changed
- The `DataGrid` updates it's values to complete the process.

The issue currently lies in the very last step. Once the collection changed event is complete the wrapped parameter value matches the parameter value from the API, but the DataGrid will not redraw the information. Once you minimize the window, click into the cell, or scroll the DataGrid to where the cell is not visible the cell will show the new value when it comes back into view.

I can't seem to find a way to keep with MVVM principles and force the cells to redraw with their updated value. Am I missing something with this? How do I get the DataGrid to update without having to completely clear and reset the `ObservableCollection` items?

**Things I have Tried**

- I had to create a custom `ObservableCollection` to implement INPC for the items in the collection, and from debugging it appears to work as intended. Each time an item in the `ObservableCollection` is updated it makes the change subscribes it to INPC and raises the collection changed event.
- For each of the columns I have the binding set to `Mode="TwoWay"` and have tried setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"`, and neither helped.
- I originally was using a `<ContentPresenter/>` in a `<DataGridTemplteColumn/>` to present different cell types, but even using a basic `<DataGridTextColumn` doesn't work.

### **---- CODE ----**

**XAML:**

```xaml
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding TestingParameters, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Name"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Path=ParamValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Param Value">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpdateParametersCommand}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**C# ViewModel**

```csharp
public class ViewModelParameterPane : ViewModelBase
{
    private ExternalEvent _event;
    private HandlerED _handler;
    private UIApplication _uiapp;
    private UIDocument _uidoc;
    private Document _doc;
    
    private TestObservableCollection<WrappedParameter> _testParameter = new TestObservableCollection<WrappedParameter>();
    public TestObservableCollection<WrappedParameter> TestParameter
    {
        get => _testParameter;
        set
        {
            _testParameter = value;
            RaiseProperty(nameof(_testParameter));
        }
    }

    public ViewModelParameterPane(ExternalEvent exEvent, HandlerED handler, UIApplication uiapp)
    {
        _event = exEvent;
        _handler = handler;
        _uiapp = uiapp;
        _uidoc = _uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
        _doc = _uidoc.Document;

        _testParameter.ItemPropertyChanged += _testParameter_ItemPropertyChanged;
        _testParameter.CollectionChanged += _testParameter_CollectionChanged;

        UpdateParametersCommand = new RelayCommand(CallUpdateParameters);
        
    }

    private void _testParameter_ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs<WrappedParameter> e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("PROPERTY CHANGE");
        RaiseProperty(nameof(TestParameter));
        int index = TestParameter.IndexOf(e.Item);
        TestParameter[index] = e.Item;
    }

    private void _testParameter_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("COLLECTION CHANGE");
    }

    private void MakeRequest(RequestIdED request)
    {
        _handler.Request.Make(request);
        _event.Raise();
    }

    private void CallUpdateParameters() { MakeRequest(RequestIdED.UpdateParameters); }

    public void UpdateParameters()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Running Update Parameters");

        try
        {
            using (var transaction = new Transaction(_doc))
            {
                transaction.Start("T_UpdateParameters");

                foreach (WrappedParameter p in TestParameter)
                {
                    string currenValue = p.RevitParameter.AsValueString();
                    if (p.RevitParameter.AsValueString() != p.ParamValue)
                    {
                        bool setValueSuccess = p.SetRevitParameterValue(p.ParamValue);
                        if(!setValueSuccess)
                        {
                            TaskDialog.Show("Parameter Value Not Set", "The parameter value for the parameter " + p.Name + " was not given a valid value and was not changed. Please ensure the units are correct.");
                        }
                    }
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Something Went Wrong. Check your values.");
        }
    }

    public void UpdateParameterValues()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < TestParameter.Count; i++)
        {
            TestParameter[i].UpdateValues();
        }
    }
}
```

**C# Parameter Wrapper Class**

```csharp
public class TestParameter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    internal void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set 
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_name));
        }
    }

    private string _categories;
    public string Categories
    {
        get => _categories;
        set
        {
            _categories = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_categories));
        }
    }

    private string _paramValue;
    public string ParamValue
    {
        get => _paramValue;
        set
        {
            _paramValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_paramValue));
        }
    }

    private Parameter _revitParameter;
    public Parameter RevitParameter
    {
        get => _revitParameter;
        set
        {
            _revitParameter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_revitParameter));
        }
    }

    private ElementId _elementId;
    public ElementId ElementId
    {
        get => _elementId;
        set
        {
            _elementId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_elementId));
        }
    }

    public TestParameter(Parameter param)
    {
        GetRevitParameterValue();
    }

    public void GetRevitParameterValue()
    {
        //Get parameter value logic
    }

    public bool SetRevitParameterValue(string Value)
    {
        //Set parameter value logic
    }
}
```

**C# TestObservableCollection Class**

```csharp
public class TestObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler<ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs<T>> ItemPropertyChanged;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        var item = this[index];
        base.RemoveItem(index);
        item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
        }

        base.ClearItems();
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        var oldItem = this[index];
        oldItem.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
        base.SetItem(index, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnItemPropertyChanged((T)sender, e.PropertyName);
    }

    private void OnItemPropertyChanged(T item, string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.ItemPropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs<T>(item, propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public sealed class ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{ 
    private readonly T _item;
    private readonly string _propertyName;

    public ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs(T item, string propertyName)
    {
        _item = item;
        _propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public T Item
    {
        get { return _item; }
    }

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get { return _propertyName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You say the collection is filtered.  Is this filtering based upon the individual properties of the elements in the collection? In other words, is it possible that changing the properties of one element in the collection can cause element to be filtered out when it was not before?   Because if so, then I think what you need is a `CollectionView` and CollectionView Live Filtering -- all based upon the standard `ObservableCollection.`  I can elaborate but you need to answer this question first, I think

Comment: @jnyp: What value/property/columns is not updated as expected when you do what exactly?

Comment: @Joe, it is filtered prior to the items being added to the `ObservableCollection` and from there no additional filtering is done. So I don't believe the changed item would be filtered out of the collection.

Comment: @mm8 the only value that can change is the paramValue column. The value is changed by editing a cell, and then once the focus is passed back to Revit, Revit recalculates inside the family and the parameter values are updated with the new calculated values. Then Revit hooks my addin again and updates the changed parameter values in the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Then I do not understand why you need `TestObservableCollection` in the first place.  The entire `ItemPropertyChanged` things seems unnecessary.   If your grid binds its columns to a regular `ObservableCollection` containing instances of `TestParameter`, and you then change any value in any `TestParameter` object inside that collection, that `TestParameter` will raise `PropertyChanged` and that change should be immediately reflected in the grid.

Comment: @Joe, as I understand it the `ObservableCollection` class does not update a WPF control on a `PropertyChanged` event for the items contained within it. It only updates the `DataGrid` on its own `CollectionChanged` event. I have tested it with using both the `ObservableCollection` and `TestObservableCollection` and neither forces the `DataGrid` to redraw. The reason I was using the `TestObservableCollection` was to raise the `CollectionChanged` event when a contained item raises its `PropertyChanged` event. Am I wrong in my research?

Comment: As long as you are neither adding items to nor removing items from the collection, there should be no need.  The data grid binds each cell to one property on one single  `WrappedParameter` object (the one that represents the row)..  When you change the `ParamValue` of one of those `WrappedParameters`, it raises an individual `PropertyChanged` event for that `ParamValue` property.  The DataGrid cell bound to this single object's `ParamValue` should update automatically.

Comment: I thnk see what your problem is.  You are using the wrong string in your `PropertyChanged`  You are using the name of the private variable.  It should instead be the name of the public property.  So don't do this: 
 `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_paramValue));`  Do this  `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ParamValue));`

Comment: @Joe you are a genius! Can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much for the help!